# fifth div stacks on top of fourth

Tags: html, css

First off, I keep trying to make the boxes move down so you can see the shadows (if there's an easier way, I'd love to hear it), but when I put them all down, they are right under one another again, so you can't see them.

Second, and this is the most important, the fifth div box stacks right on top of the fourth. I have NO clue why. I did the fifth just like the fourth. I really hope it isn't a stupid question, but I've scoured my code to find it, and I just can't.

```
 <head>
  <style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, body {
        font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .topp {
        margin-right: 500px;
        background-image: url('gamerbeta.jpg');
        background-color: fff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 430px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
    }

    .second {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        background-color: #white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 430px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
    }
        .secondword {
            position:absolute;
            top: -30px;
            left: 435px;
            font-size: 50px;
        }

        .secondp {
            position:absolute;
            top: 80px;
            left: 1000px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        .secondimage {
            position: absolute;
            top: 190px;
            left: 1230px;
        }

        .secondwordtwo {
            position:absolute;
            top: 300px;
            left: 1180px;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        .arrow {
            position: absolute;
            top: 370px;
            left: 900px;
        }

    .third {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        background-color: #D8D8D8;
        width: 100%;
        height: 430px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
    }
        .thirdword {
            position:absolute;
            top: 130px;
            left: 350px;
            font-size: 38px;
        }

        .thirdp {
            position:absolute;
            top:200px;
            left:350px;
            font-size: 26px;
            width: 670px;
        }

        .thirdpic {
            position:absolute;
            top: 25px;
            left:1150px;
        }

    .fourth {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        height: 430px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
    }
        .fourthpic {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 460px;

        }
        .fourthword {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 540px;
            font-size: 38px;
            width: 500px;
        }
        .fourthp {
            position: absolute;
            top: 170px;
            left: 540px;
            font-size: 26px;
            width: 650px;
        }

    .fifth {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        height: 430px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #D8D8D8;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
    }
   </style>
  </head>

    <body>
    <div class=topp></div>

    <div class=second>
      <div class=secondword><h1>BETA</h1></div>
      <div class=secondp>EXCLUSIVE ACHIEVEMENT<br>FOR JOINING BETA</div>
      <div class=secondimage><img src="test.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class=secondwordtwo>Beta Tester</div>
      <div class=arrow><img src="arrow.png" alt="" height="42" width="42"></div>
    </div>


    <div class=third>
      <div class=thirdword>FIND GAMERS JUST LIKE YOU...</div>
      <div class=thirdp>test here to show you</div>
      <div class=thirdpic><img src="gamer.png" alt="" height="375" 
        width="394"></div>
    </div>

    <div class=fourth>
    <div class=fourthpic><img src="dream.jpg" alt="" height="420" width="420"
    </div>
    <div class=fourthword>STAY CONNECTED...</div>
    <div class=fourthp>test here to show you</div>
    </div>

    <div class=fifth>

    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You have serious formatting issues, @PathOfFenix. The class names of your elements need to go inside quotes, like this: `<div class="fifth">`. That's probably why your CSS does not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adrei mentioned, the class names need to be between double quotes.

Also, you were missing an ending triangle bracket (**>**) on line 145 for your image tag.

```
<img src="dream.jpg" alt="" height="420" width="420">
```

Comment: Believe it or not, it wasn't the class name part (though I fixed that). It was the (>). Thanks to both of you though! :)

Comment: Hey, I was wondering about question one. I basically have a box-shadow, but it isn't appearing. I tried to move the boxes below them lower, but they didn't move. Any ideas?

Comment: @PathOfFenix probably best to post a new question with code that has the fixes in this question made to it.